# Why am I getting "list index out of range" when the index ISN'T out of range?

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, int

The goal is to return the sum of the first 2 elements of an array.

Most of the test cases work with just the first part of the if statement except the cases where nums (an array of ints) is less than 2. I can't use loops. Why am I getting "list index out of range" error?

```
def sum2(nums):
  if len(nums) >= 2:
    a = nums[0] + nums[1]
    return a
  elif len(nums) < 2:
    return nums[0]
```

Comment: `len(nums) < 2` is true when `nums = []`, so you get error when trying to access to `nums[0]`

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
def sum2(nums):
  if len(nums) >= 2:
    a = nums[0] + nums[1]
    return a
  elif len(nums) == 0: #If list is empty
      return 0
  elif len(nums) < 2:
    return nums[0]

s = []

print(sum2(s))
```